# get_posts displaying wrong permalink for "continue reading" link

Tags: permalinks, shortcode, get-posts, excerpt, read-more

I lifted the "continue reading" link functions from the Twenty Eleven theme and for the most part, it is working (works in RSS feeds).

I created a shortcode to display the latest post on the front static page using `get_posts`, however, the "continue reading" link just links to the front page instead of the post page.

```
function gavsiu_continue_reading_link() {
    return ' <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . __( 'Read more <span class="meta-nav">&raquo;</span>' ) . '</a>';
}

function gavsiu_auto_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return ' &hellip;' . gavsiu_continue_reading_link();
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'gavsiu_auto_excerpt_more' );

function gavsiu_custom_excerpt_more( $output ) {
    if ( has_excerpt() && ! is_attachment() ) {
        $output .= gavsiu_continue_reading_link();
    }
    return $output;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'gavsiu_custom_excerpt_more' );
```

Shortcode:

```
function gavsiu_recent_posts( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'cat'            => 3,
        'max_posts'      => 1
    ), $atts ) );

    $recent_posts = get_posts( array(
        'category'       => "{$cat}",
        'numberposts'    => "{$max_posts}"
    ) );

    foreach($recent_posts as $recent_post) : setup_postdata($recent_post);
        $post = '<h4 class="recent-post-title c0">' . $recent_post->post_title . '</h4>';
        $post .= '<p class="recent-content c0">' . get_the_excerpt() . '</p>';

        return $post;
    endforeach;
}

add_shortcode( 'recent_posts', 'gavsiu_recent_posts' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function gavsiu_recent_posts( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'cat'            => 3,
        'max_posts'      => 1
    ), $atts ) );

    $recent_posts = get_posts( array(
        'category'       => "{$cat}",
        'numberposts'    => "{$max_posts}",
        'offset' => 0
    ) );

    foreach($recent_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
        $permalink = ' <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink( $post->ID ) ) . '" title="Permalink to ' . esc_attr( $post->post_title ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . __( 'Read more <span class="meta-nav">&raquo;</span>' ) . '</a>';

        $return = '<h4 class="recent-post-title">' . $post->post_title . "</h4>\n";
        if ( $post->post_excerpt == '' ) :
            $return .= preg_replace( array( '/ <a href="http:\/\/gavsiu.com\/" title="Permalink to ".*?<\/a>/', '/<p .*?>/' ), array( $permalink, '<p>' ), get_the_excerpt() ) . "\n";
        else :
            $return .= '<p>' . $post->post_excerpt . $permalink . "</p>\n";
        endif;

        return $return;
    endforeach;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the post data after your get_posts loop since your calling setup_postdata. It would be better to remove the setup_postdata all together.

```
global $post;
$recent_posts = get_posts( $yourargshere );
    foreach($recent_posts as $post) : 
        $return = '<h4 class="recent-post-title c0">' . $post->post_title . '</h4>'; 
        $return .= '<p class="recent-content c0">' . apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', $post->post_excerpt ) . '</p>';
    return $return;
    endforeach;
```

You also need to change your add_filter to the_excerpt instead of get_the_excerpt

Comment: It doesn't show the excerpt this way, it's blank. Also, it adds the comments_template from the post to my front static page.